# Why does std::for_each on a map call the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, lambda, c++14

I have the following simple example, in which I want to call `std::for_each` on a collection of objects that are non-copyable:

```
class A {
public:
    A() : x(0) {}
    A(const A&) = delete;

private:
    int x;
};

void func() {
    std::vector<A> v(10);
    std::map<int, A> m;

    // works as expected
    std::for_each(begin(v), end(v), [](const A& a) { /* do nothing */ });

    // error calling copy constructor
    std::for_each(begin(m), end(m), [](const std::pair<int, A>& a) { /* do nothing */ });
}
```

If I put everything into a `std::vector`, it works as I expected, but when using a `std::map`, suddenly `std::for_each` wants to call the (deleted) copy constructor. Why? I would have assumed that I simply get a reference to the pair that is saved in the map, without any necessary copies.

Comment: @fschoenm see the answer or the answers in the linked, very similar question

Comment: Thanks, my question has been answered. I didn't find the other post because I searched "for_each" instead of "foreach" and the search engine didn't show the other result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that `std::map` has a `std::pair<const Key, Value>` as its internal value type. Rather than explicitly specifying this, Standard Library containers allow you to extract this from the container type:

In C++11 do (same as in C++98, but you would have to use a function object rather than a lambda inside `for_each`, and also use `typedef` instead of `using =`):

```
using value_type = std::map<int, A>::value_type;
std::for_each(begin(m), end(m), [](value_type const& a) { /* do nothing */ });
```

In C++14 do:

```
std::for_each(begin(m), end(m), [](auto const& a) { /* do nothing */ });
```

The use of `auto` inside the lambda is supported by Clang 3.4, Visual Studio 2013 November CTP, and GCC 4.9.

Comment: A lambda in C++03 would be pushing it :) I think you mean C++11 and C++1y respectively.

Comment: Thanks! I knew that ``std::map`` now has a constant key. I just didn't make the connection and my compiler was less than helpful with its error messages.

Comment: Also note that `std::for_each(begin(m), end(m), [](std::pair<int, A const&> a) { /* do nothing */ })` should work: copy the key, but take a reference to the value.

Comment: @Yakk true, but for generic code explicit types are more verbose, and copy + ref is expensive (e.g. if key is `std::string`)

Comment: Could someone fix the form typo into from.

Comment: @Herbert tnx, fixed!